# The command `strings` produce abnormal output

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina

Normally the shell command `cat /dev/urandom | strings -n16` would produce a list of ASCII strings useful for picking passwords. However, after the latest upgrade to MacOS Catalina `strings` output garbage ala:

```
`�e�ID�b,�e���S��qx�u�
7�Ա�H�t�>��L�b2
�g�(���<:�}�TZ,=���צ{���
�;y��9M��(���}=M
��fa��>�-�3&�syiJ`\t}�Dde7�
����\�^���1�uN{>l�V�L3
�E�y�?6�5q��Ii9�
...
```

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *seems* that the `strings` command now honours the locale settings in the [environment](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html), in particular

> LC_CTYPE
>
> This variable determines the locale category for character handling
>   functions, such as tolower(), toupper() and isalpha(). This
>   environment variable determines the interpretation of sequences of
>   bytes of text data as characters (for example, single- as opposed to
>   multi-byte characters), the classification of characters (for example,
>   alpha, digit, graph) and the behaviour of character classes.
>   Additional semantics of this variable, if any, are
>   implementation-dependent.

Setting `LC_CTYPE` to `C` restores the previous behaviour:

```
% cat /dev/urandom | LC_CTYPE=C strings -n 16
X! \*H=:e9c1`nzWk
$Hr/Q9q_b:BE-tS,[
/]59=+fPU"x-B9kk
:"*J9{5Q-tFpL=Xm$>
...
```

An alternative approach (taken from [Shell Script /dev/urandom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19224834) on Stack Overflow with minor modifications) is to filter out non-printable characters with the `tr` tool and take the first 16 characters with `dd`:

```
% cat /dev/urandom | LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc '[:print:]' | dd bs=16 count=1 2> /dev/null
```

This is much faster because it does not wait for 16 *consecutive* printable characters from the random source.